# Scheduled startup/wake while on battery power

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, battery, macos

I would like to automatically turn my Macbook Pro on at a certain time in the future (preferably with Terminal). However, I found out that this does not work when the computer is not connected to a power source. Is it possible to be able to do this on battery power?

I tried to use `pmset schedule wakeorpoweron` but that also only works on AC power.

(I need to be able to do this so I can run a program at a certain time of day. And I do not want to use `caffeinate` because it would drain the battery significantly more)

Comment: Oh, and this is apparently possible with windows devices

Comment: Maybe editing the `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.AutoWake.plist` file might work?

Comment: P.S. I also asked this question on the Mac support pages, but I dont think they will answer for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not schedule your Mac to power on when it is battery powered.

### Design Choice & Deliberate Limitation

A scheduled power on event requires the Mac be connected to mains power. This is a deliberate limitation enforced by Apple's engineers. This is to protect your Mac from powering on while in confined or poorly ventilated spaces such as in luggage. In these situations your Mac risks overheating and being damaged.

Being able to power on while on battery is a common feature request to my [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) software. Sadly it is not possible without risking damage.

Comment: Oh well, that is sad. But what I don't understand is, is that all the other companies allow it. For example, Windows has a feature to allow in battery power in their task manager. How come apple cant do the same thing?

Comment: Apple side-step the problems of heat dispersal this way. Feel free to [let Apple know directly](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) this is a feature you would value.